# ie 7 and below issue, absolute positioning

Tags: internet-explorer-7, position, absolute

for some reason in ie 7 and lower there is a huge gap  in the content. I think it has to do with some jQuery I have running. the menu seems to push the content down even though its absolute position and it shouldn't be in the flow?

http://www.tigerstudiodesign.com/company-overview/

ie 7 and below: http://localhostr.com/files/yshCtut/Screen+shot+2011-09-27+at+11.08.20+AM.jpg

what it should look like:
http://localhostr.com/files/Gq1DiuR/Screen+shot+2011-09-27+at+11.08.40+AM.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
#header {position: relative;}
#content {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 135px; height: 40px; }
```

Comment: that breaks it pretty hard. my layout is mostly floated, its just the menu that has absolute elements on it.